# Re-arranging div elements on window resize

Tags: css, mobile, frontend, window-resize, visual-web-developer

I created a personal website to practice front-end web development. I would like to learn how to re-arrange div elements as the window resizes (also to make it more mobile-friendly). As you can see in my projects page, if my window size decreases to a certain size, my project elements do not align properly and it looks sloppy. I also am running into issues with my navbar on window resize:

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

**Code on github:** [here](https://github.com/fhcheng/website)

**Projects page CSS file:** [here](https://github.com/fhcheng/website/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/projects.css.scss)

I have researched into media queries but I don't really understand how to implement them, or how to implement them in relation to my code. Advice is much appreciated.

**Added Projects code:**

```
.projectBody
    %br
    .row
        .col-md-4
            %a{:href => "javascript:void(0)", :onclick => "document.getElementById('i2share1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"}
                %img{:src => "http://res.cloudinary.com/fayecheng/image/upload/v1470786049/i2share_eew32c_jzpoi4.png", :id => "i2share"}
    #i2share1.white_content

        %a{:href => "javascript:void(0)", :onclick => "document.getElementById('i2share1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"}

            .exit
                &#215;
        = render template: "layouts/_i2share1"

    .col-md-4
        %a{:href => "javascript:void(0)", :onclick => "document.getElementById('lilypad1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"}
            %img{:src => "http://res.cloudinary.com/fayecheng/image/upload/v1470786235/lilypad1_pm2k4o_pvok8n.png", :id => "lilypad"}
    #lilypad1.white_content
        %a{:href => "javascript:void(0)", :onclick => "document.getElementById('lilypad1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"}
            .exit
                &#215;
        = render template: "layouts/_lilypad1"

    .col-md-4
        %a{:href => "javascript:void(0)", :onclick => "document.getElementById('pinkThink1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"}
            %img{:src => "http://res.cloudinary.com/fayecheng/image/upload/v1470786389/pinkthink_uhp98v_s9af6c.png", :id => "pinkThink"}
    #pinkThink1.white_content
        %a{:href => "javascript:void(0)", :onclick => "document.getElementById('pinkThink1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"}
            .exit
                &#215;
        = render template: "layouts/_pinkThink1"
%br
.row
    .col-md-4
        %a{:href => "javascript:void(0)", :onclick => "document.getElementById('platina1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"}
            %img{:src => "http://res.cloudinary.com/fayecheng/image/upload/v1470786536/platina_ncri1r_dwkrke.png", :id => "platina"}
    #platina1.white_content
        %a{:href => "javascript:void(0)", :onclick => "document.getElementById('platina1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"}
            .exit
                &#215;
        = render template: "layouts/_platina1"

    .col-md-4
        %a{:href => "javascript:void(0)", :onclick => "document.getElementById('tech4all1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"}
            %img{:src => "http://res.cloudinary.com/fayecheng/image/upload/v1470786601/tech4all_pctlqy_oqw2ux.png", :id => "tech4all"}
    #tech4all1.white_content
        %a{:href => "javascript:void(0)", :onclick => "document.getElementById('tech4all1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"}
            .exit
                &#215;
        = render template: "layouts/_tech4all1"

    .col-md-4
        %a{:href => "javascript:void(0)", :onclick => "document.getElementById('website1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"}
            %img{:src => "http://res.cloudinary.com/fayecheng/image/upload/v1470786669/website1_aouvco_xqnijl.png", :id => "website"}
    #website1.white_content
        %a{:href => "javascript:void(0)", :onclick => "document.getElementById('website1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"}
            .exit
                &#215;
        = render template: "layouts/_website1"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please include your code in your post and not just links to it. If those links become invalid in the future, then the usefulness of your post for future visitors is greatly depreciated.

Comment: The main issues is that you're ignoring and overwriting what `.col-md-4` does. The values you have applied to that class cause the `.col-md-4` elements to be wider than they should be at certain screen sizes which cause a premature reflow of those elements resulting in what you seen in the second screenshot. Removing the set width and adjusted padding to `.col-md-4` will alleviate a lot of your problems.

Comment: Final rendered HTML and CSS please, no templates. The code you have included does not provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).